# Looking for studs in thick plasterboard to attach 12" kitchen cabinet

Tags: drywall, kitchens, anchor, drywall-anchor

I have the Ikea 12" kitchen cabinet. It is standalone (between sink that's separately attached and stove). It is a pullout, so I need to attach it to wall.

I cannot find the studs in that wall at all. I have the Franklin sensor that just shows that theres something there for 80% of the space behind the cabinet, and it varies as i move it up and down.

When I use a strong magnet (type that can hold a hammer) - it stick to a small horizontal part above the cabinet but does not feel anything below it (so not a stud).

2 part question:

1 - how can I find a stud (I dragged the franklin sensor and magnet across that whole wall and not getting anything reliable)

2 - potentially it is a concrete wall or somehow solid? (it's between my apartment and neighbors). The building was build in 1930s, can I use on of the screw in anchors regardless of whether its a stud or not? and would it be safe to use? I don't foresee us putting anything extremely heavy into the kitchen cabinet, but I expect there will be pots and dishes.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's a lathe and plaster wall, which can give stud finders fits. Since it's behind a cabinet anyway try measuring from a known stud and drilling a test hole with a small bit. You know there will be studs at windows and alongside electrical boxes. (Though you may need to remove the over plate and peek to find the correct side.)

Comment: when i say 'behind a cabinet' i meant behind the cabinet that i want to attach, i'll have to do test holes as you said, there's an electrical box on the other end of the wall, and i think the studs are 16" apart in the house, so ill try that out first.

Comment: If you can't find a stud, being a 12" cabinet, then yes, you can use an anchor system. But rather that the little plastic ones, try a metal one, one that will support more weight than you think you might have. Or a hurricane/earthquake strap. If you are just holding it to the wall to keep from moving, you won't have a lot of weight to it in that regards, and you could probably use 2 of the plastic anchors, one top and one lower down.